# stream in just a random sample JSON file

Tags: json, r, dplyr

I have 24 large JSON files and I just need a small random sample of each file. Is it possible to pick the sample along with "stream_in" of this files? The problem is that some files are so large, so that it is not possible to stream_in the whole file or open the whole file in r.

So far I did the stream_in and sampling like this:

```
Beauty <- stream_in(file("Beauty_5.json"))
beauty_sample_operational <- sample_n(Beauty, 385)
```

Is it possible to combine this two steps?

Used packadges:

```
dplyr
jsonlite
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do :

```
my_files <- list(...list here your files...)
purrr::map(my_files, ~ stream_in(file(.x)) %>% sample_n(385))
```

Comment: When I do this I get this error: `my_files <- list("Beauty_5.json")` (This comand works, but not this): 
`map(my_files, ~ stream_in(file(.x)) %>% sample_n(385)) opening file input connection.
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection`

Comment: This error specify that `stream_in_line` does not find the file `"Beauty_5.json"`. Is `"Beauty_5.json"` in your current working directory? Have you tried with specifying the whole paths to the files in your list () maybe with `my_files <- list.files(pattern = 'json', full.names = TRUE)`?